# How to show this: Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Show that the subset $(0,2) \cup \{4,5\}$ is disconnected.

Tags: general-topology

How to show this: Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. Show that the subset $(0,2) \cup \{4,5\}$ is disconnected.

My head is aching with regards to this, please help me get out of this. Thank you.

Comment: On a purely intuitive level: spaces are disconnected if they have multiple connected components, so to speak. If you draw your set on paper, you'll quickly see that it has three such components. You just need to show that these components are open in the subspace topology.

Comment: What is the meaning of "disconnected"? If you mean the usual definition of "non-connected", then you just need to realize that $G_1 = (-\infty,3)$ and $G_2 = (3,+\infty)$ are two disjoint open sets that contain your original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,2)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and so also open in the subspace $A:= (0,2) \cup \{4,5\}$. (Open subsets in $A$ are of the form $O \cap A$ where $O$ is open in $\Bbb R$, i.e. $O$ is a union of open intervals).

$\{4,5\}$ is also open in $A$ as it equals $(3,6) \cap A$ e.g.

If you can write a subspace $A$ as a disjoint union of non-empty open sets $A$ is disconnected by definition.

We've found two such sets, so we're done and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score -1):

The usual topology is the Euclidean topology, ie, the topology generated by open intervals (more generally open balls, in $\Bbb R^n$) with radii defined through the Euclidean metric.

A subset is disconnected if there exists a pair of points for which there is no path over this subset linking the two.

Take any point of $(0,2)$ and $4$; or take any point of $(0,2)$ and $5$; or take $4$ and $5$. For any of these pairs of point, the path would have to cross a subset of $\Bbb R$ (specifically $[2,4)$, $(4,5)$ or both) which is not contained in $S = (0,2) \cup \{4\} \cup \{5\}$. The subset $S$ is thus disconnected for $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.

Comment: Your solution shows that the set is not $\textit{path-connected}$, which is a different concept than connected. It is true that path-connected implies connected, but the converse is false. For example, the infinite broom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom) is connected but not path-connected.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I didn't know there was a distinction and was wondering why I was downvoted :)